# error in MpChart while retrieve value from database

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

[image]

while i retrieve value from database for mpChart,it showing the below error. please help me, i checked whole stackoverflow and google but didnt found the answer.

Comment: you are inserting wrong values to LineDataSet.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
xweight = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
```

to:

```
xweight = new ArrayList<Entry>();
```

Also make sure you import the correct statement for Entry class such as:

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
```

Comment: i want to retrieve data from database, and i set getter and setter in database model, so now how i can apply it with Entry